# javascript init an object without the new keyword

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between:

```
function Foo(){} var foo1 = Foo();
```

and

```
var foo2 = new Foo()
```

As far as I tested, foo1 gives nothing. typeof foo1 is undefined while with new it's ok as expected.

What's the reason the that without the new keyword I get the undefined result?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) to get an understanding of the new keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `function Foo(){}` returns `undefined` implicitly, i.e. if a function does not have an explicit return statement, the compiler/VM will implicitly add it. However, when you use the `new` keyword, you instantiate an object from the constructor function.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/556770) for an exact explanation for what the `new` keyword does.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's basically happening when you are using `new`, it:

1. Creates a new object, let it be `o`.
2. Sets the prototype link of `o` to `[constructor].prototype`.
3. Executes the `[constructor]` with `o` as the context object (`this`).
4. Returns `o` unless the `[consructor]` returns a non-primitive value. In that case, that non-primitive value is returned instead of `o`. (Added these precisions as suggested by @Esailija).

When you are not using `new`, nothing of this happens and the context object is `window`, unless the function was invoked on another object. In this case, the context object would be that object.

E.g.

```
function A() {}
A(); //this points to window

var o = { A: A };

o.A(); //this points to o
```

Every `function` can be a constructor in JavaScript, however you must use the `new` keyword in order to get the expected result.

To avoid mistakes, some people will design their function so that forgetting the `new` keyword will not be harmful, like below, however there are better alternatives to detect these mistakes, like using code analysis tools like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/).

E.g.

```
function Foo(args) {
    if (!(this instanceof Foo)) {
        return new Foo(args);
    }
    //initialization code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code contained a safeguard to bail if the new keyword wasn't used. Which is a good idea because if the new keyword is omitted, the context will be a window.

```
function MyConstructor(){
  console.log(this.toString());
}

var instance1 = MyConstructor();
var instance2 = new MyConstructor();
```

This outputs:

```
"[object Window]"
"[object Object]"
```

So, in your example it shows undefined as a window which is bind automatically has no foo1 method,
in the second case, new instantiate/declare an object has method foo2

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
function Foo(){} var foo1 = Foo();
```

instead of

```
function Foo(){} var foo1 = foo();
```

JavaScript is case sensitive language